# Webpack aliases not resolving SCSS partials when using _ (underscore)

Tags: webpack, sass

Long story short, using scss partials (underscored filenames) doesn't seem to work when combined with aliases?! Or am I doing something wrong? Webpack v.4.41

**/core/styles/_core.scss**

```
body { awesome: style }
```

**/app/styles/style.scss**

```
import '@core/core';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@core': path.resolve(__dirname, './core/styles')
    }
  }
}
```

This throws an error: `SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: @core/core.`
However, if I change the import to `@core/_core` it works correctly.

Comment: Is your file has path `core/styles/_core` ?

Comment: @nickbullock yes, the path is correct because `@import '@core/_core';` works, but `@import '@core/core';` doesn't

Comment: It is working as expected as i can see. If you want to `@import '@core/_core'` you need to rename file `_core.scss` to `core.scss`. `_core` it is just file name and it is not related to alias at all.

Comment: According to SCSS documentation, partials are defined with `_` and resolved as regular files: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#partials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently when dealing with aliases and scss imports, you are supposed to prefix your import with tilde `~` and define the alias itself without it:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'core': path.resolve(__dirname, './core/styles')
    }
  }
}
```

**style.scss**

```
@import '~core/core';
// correctly imports the ./core/styles/_core.scss
```

Comment: [Webpacks docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules) states using `~` is deprecated